# Jumping text on top of jquery div animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I want to have some text in a colored block that animates. The end result is supposed to be like a thermometer that rises when the user clicks on certain temperatures, but I'm not there yet!

Anyway, I thought I could do this by putting a red `div` on the bottom, then another `div` with a picture of a thermometer, and then the numbers on top, as text. Then, I could use a basic jQuery CSS animation to move the red div up the thermometer when I click on the numbers.

I have this Javascript so far:

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
  $("#1").click(function(){
    $("#box").animate({height:"300px"},"slow");
  });
  $("#2").click(function(){
    $("#box").animate({height:"100px"},"slow");
  });
});
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="box" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;margin:6px;">
    <p id='1'>hello</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p id='2'>goodbye</p>
</div>
```

When I click the "hello" `p`, the green square expands as it should, and when I click on the "goodbye" `p`, the green square contracts exactly as it should—but both times, the text jumps.

Is there a way to get around this? It is a rather simple animation, but I'm not too skilled in jQuery.

Comment: It's working fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/W77T5/

Comment: i checked on jsfiddle it's all ok. what do you mean by 'the text jumps'? http://jsfiddle.net/bondythegreat/XyLNG/

Answer (score 0):

Use this css:

```
p {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Check it on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9n8py61o/)